# The index value does not increase according to conditions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

There are 15 clickable objects on the scene. There are 5 tokens in an array. User needs to match correct 5 with that tokens. User clicks 5 of them (correct five and correct order). So, every time click action called, the code increases the index value. The code uses index to travel along the arrays. But index value keeps turning back to 0. What am I missing here?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class CipherClickHandler : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    public Text[] alanlar = new Text[5];
    private string[] clickedWords = new string[5];
    private string[] solution = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
    private int index = 0;
    private int counter = 0;
    private bool success = false;

    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        if (success)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            if (index < 5)
            {
                clickedWords[index] = this.gameObject.name;
                this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                alanlar[index].text = clickedWords[index];
                ControlCipher(clickedWords[index]);
                index += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                index = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    private void ClearBlanks()
    {
        ...
    }

    private void ControlCipher(string token)
    {
        if (counter < 5)
        {
            if (token == solution[index])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            PuzzleSolved();
            success = true;
        }
    }

    private void PuzzleSolved()
    {
        ...
    }

    private IEnumerator CoroutineSuccess()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

When I trace index just after index < 5 control, it returns 0. When I trace after index += 1, it returns 1. But, after the next click, it again returns 0 and 1 respectively.

Comment: You should use the same index variable for both methods.

Comment: You might be running an old build. Recompile and make sure that the binary can actually be written. Otherwise, check if other methods modify index.

Comment: Pass the current value of index from OnPointerClick to ControlCipher as an argument.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I restared the Unity. Then installed a latest version but the problem persists. How can I check if the binary is written or not? Can you elaborate it if possible?

Comment: Check the file modification time on disk

Comment: each copy of this script will have its own index. therefore each one will start at 0..  you possibly want a static index thats shared between them, and on incorrect it is reset to 0

Comment: @BugFinder Yes, I realised that just now. I was looking at the wrong place. If you post it as an answer, I will gladly mark it as a solution. Thank a lot anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key issue seems to be that each item has a copy of the script, therefore each item has index at . What would fix this would be if they share an index (using static) so that the index can increment and effect for all of them, and be reset should the wrong object be selected.